# Does accepting Answers deter posting of better answers?

Tags: discussion

I ask this because @chris gave me an answer about products/integrals of sums:

[How to do algebra on summations of variable expressions?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/65471)

...but it would be a pain to incorporate the method into EVERY library function that MIGHT have to handle products of sums some day.  I Accepted to credit chris for the Answer, but I'd still like to know if there's something neater.

Comment: I think you shouldn't feel obliged to accept an answer unless it addresses your question to your complete satisfaction. If an answer was helpful but somehow did not quite meet your needs, upvoting it should be sufficient. That being said, if I came across a question with an accepted answer that I felt I could improve upon, I'd write my own answer anyway, regardless of whether it would be accepted. Acceptance is considered to be entirely the asker's prerogative, so they can switch the accept, or not, as they feel appropriate.

Answer (score 6):

In my experience [Accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) an answer *can* reduce the likelihood of receiving other answers, as (I suppose) the topic appears concluded.  It is for this reason that I always suggest waiting 24 hours before Accepting, which should allow daily visitors from anywhere in the world a chance to see and answer your question.

If after waiting a day or two to Accept you still do not have an answer that is fully satisfactory you can either wait an hope or you can put a [bounty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) on it.

Since you are a new user you lack extra "reputation" points for a bounty.  However I find your question interesting, though I have no time to explore it myself at the moment.  If you will edit your question to include several additional examples of the specific input and output that you desire, along with *Mathematica* code for your expressions (to simplify copying them) I will place a bounty on your question myself.

Comment: Thank you!  I have edited the question.  Let me know if it needs further expansion/clarification

Comment: How about to just allow the users to accept a question after 24 hrs?